# Rearrange output from "ip addr show" - possibly with awk

Tags: awk

Is it possible to rearrange awk's output?

If yes, what is the right way to do it?

```
wolf@Linux:~$ ip a s | awk '/^[0-9]/ {print $2} /inet / {print $2}'
lo:
127.0.0.1/8
enp0s3:
10.1.1.1/24
enp0s8:
172.16.1.1/24
enp0s9:o
192.168. it2?1.1/24
wolf@Linux:~$
```

Desired Output

```
wolf@Linux:~$ ip a s | <awk syntax here>
lo: 127.0.0.1/8
enp0s3: 10.1.1.1/24
enp0s8: 172.16.1.1/24
enp0s9: 192.168.1.1/24
wolf@Linux:~$
```

Comment: What does the input to the `awk` program look like?

Comment: Use the `-o` option of `ip`: `ip -o a s | awk '{print $2,$4}'`. But better don't assume that each interface has a single address.

Comment: Or that "*nobody* is using IPv6"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use printf instead of print in you awk:

```
$ ip a s | awk '/^[0-9]/ {printf "%s ", $2 } /inet / {print $2}'
```

`print`  -> will add new line in each output

`printf` -> Will print in the format you want and does not add new line.

Comment: Thanks @StalinVigneshKumar, it works! :)

Comment: @Wolf : Pleasure.

Comment: @Wolf If one of the answers solved your issue, please take a moment to [accept it](//$$SITEURL/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on [the checkmark on the left](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/203101). That will mark the question as answered and is the way that thanks are conveyed on the Stack Exchange sites.

Answer (score 1):

To rearrange the output *from the `awk` command* (i.e. not rewrite the `awk` command), pass the output through `sed 'N; y/\n/ /'`.   This will read each line from `awk`, then append the next line to that with a space in-between.

I.e.

```
ip a s | awk ... | sed 'N; y/\n/ /'
```

But rewriting the `awk` command would be the proper way to do it (but I don't have a Linux system to test it on and don't know what `ip a s` produces on your system).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want the interface name and its attached subnet. The `ip route` command will almost do this for you, with the exception of the loopback interface

```
ip route | awk '$2=="dev"'

10.1.1.0/24 dev enp0s3 proto dhcp scope link src 10.1.1.1
172.16.1.0/24 dev enp0s8 proto dhcp scope link src 172.16.1.1
192.168.1.0/24 dev enp0s9 proto dhcp scope link src 192.168.1.1 metric 202
```

A little more pickiness with `awk` and you can get

```
ip route | awk -F '[ /]' '$3=="dev" { printf "%s: %s/%s\n", $4, $10, $2 }'

enp0s3: 10.1.1.1/24
enp0s8: 172.16.1.1/24
enp0s9: 192.168.1.1/24
```

To include the loopback with this approach you would have to synthesise it, which isn't ideal

```
ip route | awk -F '[ /]' 'BEGIN { print "lo: 127.0.0.1/8" }; $3=="dev" { printf "%s: %s/%s\n", $4, $10, $2 }'

lo: 127.0.0.1/8
enp0s3: 10.1.1.1/24
enp0s8: 172.16.1.1/24
enp0s9: 192.168.1.1/24
```